# Delete a hash from array of hashes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, ruby-hash

I have array of hashes in json format, and I have to remove one of the hash from that array, I am iterating that array and if that particular key/ value matches i am deleting that hash,
I found clear() method but, clear leaves the {}, which I don't require
I want the whole hash to be removed

```
[{"question":"0a2a3452","answer":"lopq"},
 {"question":"58deacf9","answer":"admirationo"},
 {"question":"32c53e","answer":"acion"},
 {"question":"b5546bcf","answer":"figure"},
 {"question":"4f246a10","answer":"zelta"},
 {"question":"bf546c04","answer":"deltaa"}]
```

i.e if my key matches as "0a2a3452", I want to delete the first hash

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `delete_if` method:

```
arr = [{"question":"0a2a3452","answer":"lopq"},
       {"question":"58deacf9","answer":"admirationo"},
       {"question":"32c53e","answer":"acion"},
       {"question":"b5546bcf","answer":"figure"},
       {"question":"4f246a10","answer":"zelta"},
       {"question":"bf546c04","answer":"deltaa"}]

arr.delete_if {|a| a[:question] == '0a2a3452' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
items = [
  {"question":"0a2a3452","answer":"lopq"},
  {"question":"58deacf9","answer":"admirationo"},
  {"question":"32c53e","answer":"acion"},
  {"question":"b5546bcf","answer":"figure"},
  {"question":"4f246a10","answer":"zelta"},
  {"question":"bf546c04","answer":"deltaa"}
]

items = items.reject {|i| i[:question] == '0a2a3452'}
```

Comment: I think you want `reject!`, since `reject` returns a copy of the hash value.